# What dataset(s) is Marcus Winand using in his book "SQL Performance Explained"?

Tags: oracle, query-performance, performance-tuning, database-tuning, learning

I am currently reading [SQL Perfrmance Explained](https://sql-performance-explained.com/) by Marcus Winand. I would like to follow along with the queries and examples he used to explain database tuning. It would greatly allow me to understand by doing things hands on and experiment with my own queries.

I can set up a Docker container with an Oracle database and simply copy over the dataset(s) (perhaps in the form of CSV files?) into tables in the database. I just need the files themselves.

**Question: Anyone know where to find the dataset(s) Marcus Winand used in his book [SQL Perfrmance Explained](https://sql-performance-explained.com/)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book is essentially the "PDF version" of Markus' website https://use-the-index-luke.com

The website also has the scripts for each DBMS to create the sample schema and test data: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/example-schema